# Куда пропадают переносы? PHP, Markdown

Tags: строки, шаблоны, php7, phalcon, markdown

Дело такое. Храню в базе статьи. Для некоторых из них использую MarkDown. Вот кусок статьи в "редакторе" (разметка MarkDown):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что тут должно быть - ```` ```shell ```` открывает блок кода. Всё, что внутри, оборачивается на выходе в блок `<pre class="lang-shell"> ... </pre>`. Затем после загрузки на странице обрабатывается библиотекой Highlight.js для подсветки синтаксиса. Но проблема в том, что внутри блоков `pre` (и ТОЛЬКО в них! в других местах всё хорошо) таинственным образом пропадают переносы. Это в редакторе (простое поле `<textarea>`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переносы есть. Далее смотрим на странице:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переносов нет. Вообще. От слова "совсем".
Теперь мы берём и выводим содержимое `$post->body` не в шаблон, а просто через `var_dump()`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда увидим следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сначала подумал, что чудит шаблонизатор. Полез в кэш, но там всё что он делает это просто переводит директивы шаблонизатора в функции PHP. `$post->body`, в частности, он выводит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, никаких дополнительных фильтров, `trim()`ов и прочего. Просто выводит. Но переносы в коде пропадают. В какую сторону смотреть? Спасибо.

P.S. Проект построен на Phalcon PHP Framework, база MongoDB 3.4, PHP 7.0
P.P.S. Библиотека Highlight.js ни при чём. Проблема была ещё до её внедрения, и при отключении библиотеки сохраняется.

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в том, что символа `\n` для HTML не существует. Поэтому прежде чем выводить текст на страницу нужно было сначала заменить символы `\n` и `\r` на соответствующие им HTML-аналоги:

```
$post->body = str_replace( "\r", '&#13;', $post->body );
$post->body = str_replace( "\n", '&#10;', $post->body );
```

И всё стало замечательно.